# Need a command that will separate the count accounting to files that are < 1M lines and > 1M lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, solaris

Environment: Solaris 9

I have a command that gives me a total count of files. But I need a command that will separately count files that are less than 1M lines and files that are more than 1M lines long. How can I do that?

```
find . -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

Comment: You actually need two commands, correct? One to produce the list of files that are over 1M and one to produce the list of files that are < !M? Or do you want a command that shows all the file along with some indication as to whether or not the file is > 1M?

Comment: Note that if your version of `find` supports it, then using `+` in place of `\;` would be sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the -size option:

```
echo "Smaller: $(find . -type f -size -1M | wc -l)"
echo "Larger: $(find . -type f -size +1M | wc -l)"
```

When your find does not support 1M, just write the full number.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: @rojomoke's comment, I have here is a version that counts LINES in the files with the `wc` utility, since that is what you used in your original post**

Code:

```
# here I am already in the directory with the files so I just use * 
# to refer to all files
# the wc -l will return a single column of counts so I use $1 to 
# refer to field 1
wc -l * | awk '$1>1e6{bigger++}$1<1e6{smaller++}END{print "Files > 1M lines = ", bigger, "\nFiles < 1M lines = ", smaller}'
```

Output:

```
"Files > 1M lines =  454" 
"Files < 1M lines =  528"
```

Comment: The OP's use of `wc -l` makes me think he's interested if files with more or less that 1M _lines_, not characters

Comment: @rojomoke thanks, I have incorporated your comment for counting lines rather than bytes if thats what OP needs, the wording was a little unclear